# scrip class can't be found for adding c# code to unity for loading scenes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am attempting to add a c# script to python allowing me to use UnityEngine.SceneManagement to load a scene of a game for a school assignment I am completing, but whenever I try to add the code to unity I get an error message stating "Can't add script component 'menu control' because the script class cannot be found. Make sure that there are no compile errors and that the file name and class name match". I am relatively new to C# and wouldn't be surprised if there was just some small error in my code I couldn't spot. Here is my code below

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class MenuController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Levels to load")]
    public string _newGameLevel;
    private string levelToLoad;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject noSavedGameDialogue = null;

    public void newgameYes()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(_newGameLevel);
    }
    public void loadgameYes()
{
    if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("Savedlevel"))
    {
        levelToLoad = PlayerPrefs.GetString("SavedLevel");
        SceneManager.LoadScene(levelToLoad);
    }
    else
    {
      noSavedGameDialogue.SetActive(true);
    }
}
    public void QuitButton()
    {
        Application.Quit();
    }
}
```

Comment: If there aren't any compiler error make sure the class name matches with the script name `MenuController`

Comment: the names match, I'm pretty sure it's a compiler error but I'm just not sure what

Comment: Well if it where it would appear in the console in Unity ..

Comment: theres no errors in the console and the names are the same, that's the part of it I don't understand